# Envio de formulário sem recarregar a página

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Tenho um formulário pronto e funcionando normal. Mas o que preciso fazer é o seguinte.

Quando eu enviar o formulário ele não vai atualizar a página e me retorna

"Cadastrado com sucesso" ou Algum erro "Nick já existe", "E-mail inválido"

```
<form class="form3" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Nome completo</p>
    <input type="text" class="Nome" name="Nome" placeholder="Nome completo *">

    <p>Nome de usuário</p>
    <input type="text" name="Nick" placeholder="Nick da conta *">

    <p>E-mail</p>
    <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Informe seu E-mail *">

    <p>Senha</p>
    <input type="password" name="Senha" placeholder="Informe a sua senha *">

    <input type="submit" id="Bot_login" name="Cadastra" value="Criar conta">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Cadastrar'])){
        $Nome       = htmlspecialchars($_POST['Nome'],ENT_QUOTES);
        $Nick       = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Nick']),ENT_QUOTES);
        $Email      = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Email']),ENT_QUOTES);
        $Senha      = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Senha']),ENT_QUOTES);

        if($Nome == ""){
            echo 'Preencha o campo Nome corretamente!';
        }
        if($Nick == ""){
            echo 'Preencha o campo Nick corretamente!';
        }
        if($Email == ""){
            echo 'Preencha o campo E-mail corretamente!';
        }
        if($Senha == ""){
            echo 'Preencha o campo Senha corretamente!';
        }
        else{
            $SQL_Cadastro = mysqli_query($conex,"INSERT INTO UserLog (Nome, Nick, Email, Senha) VALUES ('$Nome', '$Nick', '$Email', '$Senha')");
        }
    }
    else{

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o `jQuery.ajax`, `jQuery.post`, `XMLHttpRequest` ou `Fetch` para essa funcionalidade.

---

#### `jQuery.Ajax`

O `jQuery.Ajax` é uma função baseada no `XMLHttpRequest`. Ela serve para envios de requisições do tipo GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc.

Com essas requisições você também pode enviar e receber dados. No caso do `jQuery.ajax`, basta informar na propriedade `data`, quais dados você deseja enviar.

Para capturar o retorno, há três funções que podem ser utilizadas para isso: `success` para quando houver sucesso nas requisições; `error` para quando houver erro; e `complete` para quando a requisição for finalizada.

No nosso exemplo, irei utilizar apenas a função `success`, mas fica a seu critério utilizar as outras também.

**Exemplo:**

```
$("#Bot_login").click( function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      /* URL da requisição */
      url: 'sua-url',

      /* Tipo da Requisição */
      type: 'POST',

      /* Campos que serão enviados */
      data: {
        Nome: $('input[name="Nome"]').val(),
        Nick: $('input[name="Nick"]').val(),
        Email: $('input[name="Email"]').val(),
        Senha: $('input[name="Senha"]').val()
      },

      /* Os campos abaixo são necessários quando há envio de arquivos */
      processData: false,
      cache: false,

      /* Função para quando houver sucesso na requisição */
      success: function( response ) {
        alert( response );
      }
    });

});
```

---

#### `XMLHttpRequest`

O `XMLHttpRequest` é a base do `jQuery.Ajax` e `jQuery.Post`. Ela funciona da mesma maneira, porém, com métodos e forma de envio um pouco diferente.

> `XMLHttpRequest` é uma *API* que fornece funcionalidade ao cliente para transferir dados entre um cliente e um servidor. Ele fornece uma maneira fácil de recuperar dados de um URL sem ter que fazer uma atualização de página inteira.

Na programação, isso é chamado de Ajax = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. Apesr do nome, não precisa — necessariamente — ser em XML.

**Exemplo:**

```
/**
 * Cria uma requisição e adiciona um evento
 * quando quando a requisição for finalizada
 */
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("loaded", response => {
  alert( response.target.success );
});

$("#Bot_login").click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  /* Abre uma requisição do tipo POST */
  xhr.open("POST", "sua-url", true);

  /* Envia a requisição */
  xhr.send( new FormData( document.querySelector("form") ) )

});
```

---

#### `Fetch`

O `Fetch` é uma versão alternativa do `XMLHttpRequest`, porém ela — promete — um conjunto de recursos que a deixam mais "poderosa" e flexível que a *XHR*

Essa função trabalha com objetos genéricos do tipo `Request` e `Response`. Ela é ideal para quem quer trabalhar com `Service Work`, manipulação de cache através da `Cache API`, requisições etc.

Ela só possui um parâmetro. Nesse parâmetro você pode passar uma "string" (URL) ou um objeto `Request` com as configurações de sua requisição.

**Exemplo:**

```
$("#Bot_login").click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  /* Cria uma requisiçãod o tipo POST */
  const request = new Request("sua-url", {
    method: "POST",
    body: new FormData( document.querySelector("form") )
  });

  /* Executa a requisição e retorna o resultado */
  fetch(request).then( response => {
    return response.text(); // ou return response.json();
  } )
  .then ( result => {
    alert( result );
  });

});
```

---

#### `jQuery.Post`

Essa é uma versão alternativa e compacta do `jQuery.Ajax`

```
$.post('sua-url', {
        Nome: $('input[name="Nome"]').val(),
        Nick: $('input[name="Nick"]').val(),
        Email: $('input[name="Email"]').val(),
        Senha: $('input[name="Senha"]').val()
}, function(response) {
  alert( response )
})
```

Answer (score -1):

bom dia usa as variaveis globais para exibir as mensagens na mesma pagina.
segue código alterado.

```
<form class="form3" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['msg']):
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
unset($_SESSION['msg'];
endif;
?>

<p>Nome completo</p>
<input type="text" class="Nome" name="Nome" placeholder="Nome completo *">

<p>Nome de usuário</p>
<input type="text" name="Nick" placeholder="Nick da conta *">

<p>E-mail</p>
<input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Informe seu E-mail *">

<p>Senha</p>
<input type="password" name="Senha" placeholder="Informe a sua senha *">

<input type="submit" id="Bot_login" name="Cadastra" value="Criar conta">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Cadastrar'])){
        $Nome       = htmlspecialchars($_POST['Nome'],ENT_QUOTES);
        $Nick       = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Nick']),ENT_QUOTES);
        $Email      = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Email']),ENT_QUOTES);
        $Senha      = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Senha']),ENT_QUOTES);

        if($Nome == ""){
            $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Preencha o campo Nome corretamente!';
        }
        if($Nick == ""){
            $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Preencha o campo Nick corretamente!';
        }
        if($Email == ""){
            $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Preencha o campo E-mail corretamente!';
        }
        if($Senha == ""){
            $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Preencha o campo Senha corretamente!';
        }
        else{
            $SQL_Cadastro = mysqli_query($conex,"INSERT INTO UserLog (Nome, 
Nick, Email, Senha) VALUES ('$Nome', '$Nick', '$Email', '$Senha')");
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Usuario Cadastrado com sucesso";
        }
    }
    else{
     $_SESSION['msg'] = "Erro ao cadastrar usuario";
    }
?>
```

Assim o echo $_SESSION se encarregara de mostrar cada mensagem definida e destruira logo em cima para a mensagem sumir quando a pagina for atualizada, a pagina deve ser atualizada para captação dos dados após isso ele vai definir a mensagem na variavel global e mostra-la conforme o resultado, é uma maneira simples sem precisar usar JS, angular ou qualquer outra tecnologia.

Espero ter ajudado comecei agora no ramo de desenvolvimento.